# how to do Loop in R

Tags: r, loops, random, sample

I have a question regarding loop in R.

For example, currently at t=0, there are 100 people alive. Basically, each person will be alive with a probability of exponential (-mu) in which i put the mu=0.1.

I want to generate 10 samples to get the number of people alive at t=1. So i have done and get the following.

command:

```
set.seed(123)
alive <- 100    
mu <- 0.1
sample <- 10
alive1 <- rbinom(sample,alive,exp(-mu)) 
alive1 

# [1] 92 88 91 87 86 95 90 87 90 91
```

and now, i want to keep continuing doing it until time t=20.

command :

```
alive2 <- rbinom(10,alive1,exp(-mu))
alive2
alive3 <- rbinom(10,alive2,exp(-mu))
alive3
....

alive20 <-rbinom (10,alive19,exp(-mu))
alive20
```

output :

```
alive2 <- rbinom(10,alive1,exp(-mu))
alive2

# [1] 78 80 81 78 81 82 83 83 83 77

alive3 <- rbinom(10,alive2,exp(-mu))
alive3

# [1] 67 71 72 63 72 73 75 75 77 72
```

...

however, i do not want to keep on repeating the command especially if i want to extend my time to a longer period. how do i do the looping in r for my problem?

thanks!

Comment: Do you want to keep each iteration object (`alive2`, `alive3`...) or only the final one ?

Comment: each iteration object is depending on the privious object. meaning that alive 3 is depending on alive 2. alive4 depending on alive3 and so on.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. What I ask is if you want to keep every `alive2`...`alive20` objects in your R session, or just care to get the final one.

Comment: i want to keep every alive2...alive20... and finally put all result in a matrix form so that i can see the samples and alive1..alive2..alive20 results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set.seed(123)
alive <- vector("list", 20)
mu <- 0.1
n <- 10

alive[[1]] <- rbinom(n, 100, exp(-mu))
for(i in 2:20)
    alive[[i]] <- rbinom(n, alive[[i-1]], exp(-mu))
```

I renamed the variable `sample` to `n` to avoid confusion with the commonly used function `sample()`.

Comment: Glad to help! But please tick the accept icon if it settled the matter, that's how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(123)
alive <- 100    
mu <- 0.1
sample <- 10
alive1 <- rbinom(sample,alive,exp(-mu)) 


for ( i in 2:20)
{
    assign(
        paste0("alive",i),
        rbinom(10,get(paste0("alive",(i-1))),exp(-mu))
    )
}
```

Or @Backlin's suggestion of putting it in a list -

```
set.seed(123)
alive <- 100    
mu <- 0.1
sample <- 10
Aliveset <- vector(mode = "list", length = 20)
Aliveset[[1]] <- rbinom(sample,alive,exp(-mu)) 
for ( i in 2:20)
{
Aliveset[[i]] <- rbinom(10,Aliveset[[i-1]],exp(-mu))
}
```

Comment: Don't make a fake list by naming your variables `alive1`, `alive2` etc., use a real list instead.

Comment: Error: unexpected numeric constant in "for ( 2"
> {
+ assign(
+ paste0("alive",i),
+ rbinom(10,get(paste0("alive",(i-1))),exp(-mu))
+ )
+ }
Error in paste0("alive", i) : object 'i' not found
>

Comment: Edited and incorporated @Backlin's suggestion as well